# How to To Delete The data in Localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, local-storage

what I need

- I need to toggle image on click.
- like if user select favorite choice & then it mark unfavorite image is altered and data is deleted from localstoarge.

html code

```
<div  style="display:block; float:right; width:auto; color:#7c7c7c;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="favourate_dextop" id="fav'.$data[$k]['id'].'"  onClick=" favaorite('.$data[$k]['id'].',\''.$name_event.'\',\''.$event_city.'\',\''.$event_country.'\',\''.$event_urls.'\',this)"></a>
</div>
```

js code

```
function favaorite(sess_id,name,city,country,event_url,pointer){

    var eventData;
    //is anything in localstorage?
    if (localStorage.getItem('eventData') === null) {
        eventData = [];
    } else {
        // Parse the serialized data back into an array of objects
        eventData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('eventData'));
        //alert(eventData);
        $.each(eventData, function(key, value){
            //console.log(value);
            var  imageUrl='http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phonehover.png';
            //var  imageUrl='http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phone.png';

            $(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
            //$(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
        });

    }
    var details={};

    details.sess_id=sess_id;
    details.name=name;
    details.city=city;
    details.country=country;
    details.event_url=event_url;

    // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the array
    eventData.push(details);

    // Alert the array value
    //alert(eventData);  // Should be something like [Object array]
    // Re-serialize the array back into a string and store it in localStorage
    var jsondata=localStorage.setItem('eventData', JSON.stringify(eventData));


}
```

problem

- I'm new in localstorage I need to know how could I delete data from json string.
- I have implemented *add to favorite* now I need to *mark unfavorite*.

data is stored:

```
[{
    "sess_id":182104,
    "name":"AUTOMECH FORMULA",
    "city":"Cairo",
    "country":"Egypt",
    "event_url":"automech-formula"
},]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete data from localstorage you use **localStorage.removeItem('itemNam')**

example

```
localStorage.setItem('name','hello');
```

to delete the name item from the localStorage you use

```
localStorage.removeItem('name');
```

BUT IF YOUR QUESTION IS HOW TO DELETE DATA FROM JSON OBJECT THEN YOU HAVE TWO METHODS

1: changing the original json object

**delete originalJson.attributeName**

```
   originalJson = {name:'myname',age:30};//our object to test with
```

example :

```
   delete originalJson.age //in this case originalJson.age is no more available
```

2: don't change the original object and make another copy instead

```
originalJson2 = JSON.stringify(originalJson);
  originalJson2 = JSON.parse(originalJson2);
  delete originalJson2.age //originalJson.age is available but originalJson2.age is not available
```

here is the : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamism/fwq1k6y8/)

Comment: i..need..to..use..toggle..image..when..user..unmark...fav->unfavorite

Comment: what you think about the second part that i added, is that what are you talking about ?

Comment: yes..i..need..to..delete...data..from..json..object

Comment: use the second way that i mentioned in the solution another **think  you have an additional  "," after the last object in the array** so remove it  and use the jsfiddle example i think this is what you are looking for

Comment: i had problem data is inserted on 1 clcik , but background images changes on second click.

Comment: in delete all data are deleted on click instead user whose div is clicked then data will be deleted:http://jsfiddle.net/48Lq3u60/23/

Answer (score 0):

let assume that sess_id is your unique id for events

```
function unfavorite(sess_id){

    var eventData = localStorage.getItem('eventData');

    //is anything in localstorage?
    if (localStorage.getItem('eventData') === null) {
        console.log('invalid event');
    } 
    eventData = JSON.parse(eventData);

    // Keep all without the one with specified sess_id
    $.grep(eventData, function(value) {
       return value.sess_id != sess_id;
    });

    var jsondata=localStorage.setItem('eventData', JSON.stringify(eventData));
}
```